# control android refresh time according to webpage output

Tags: android, httpurlconnection

If i have something like example.com/time.php and the output is just 20000 so How can i link this to control time of refresh, Any Idea?

```
Thread t = new Thread() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
    try {
      while (!isInterrupted()) {
        Thread.sleep(10000); // here is the number which should be linked to the webpage output 
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
          @Override
          public void run() {
            // update View here!
          }
        });
      }
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
    }
  }
};
t.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use handler for easier implementation.

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
Runnable test = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        //do work
        handler.post(test, 4000); //wait 4 sec and run again, you can change it programmatically 
    }
};

public void stopTest() {
    handler.removeCallbacks(test);
}

public void startTest() {
    handler.post(test,0); //wait 0 ms and run
}
```